# Resolving a Maven dependency differently if the JVM in use is x86 or x64?

Tags: java, maven-2, jvm, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a Maven repository set up to host some dlls, but I need my Maven projects to download different dlls depending on whether the JVM in use is x86 or x64.

So for example, on a computer running an x86 version of the JVM I need ABC.dll to be downloaded from the repository as a dependency, but on another computer running an x64 version of the JVM, I need it download XYZ.dll instead.

How would I go about doing this? An example pom.xml file would be nice.

Comment: how would you access these dlls from java ?

Answer (score 15):

This will work on any VM. You can use [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to have alternate configurations according to the environment.

A profile contains an activation block, which describes when to make the profile active, followed by the usual pom elements, such as dependencies:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <arch>x86</arch>
      </os>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <!-- your 32-bit dependencies here -->
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <arch>x64</arch>
      </os>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- your 64-bit dependencies here -->
    </dependencies>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

As you mentioned DLLs, I'm assuming this is Windows-only, so you may also want to add `<family>Windows</family>` under the `<os>` tags.

EDIT: When mixing 32-bit VM on a 64-bit OS, you can see what value the VM is giving to the `os.arch` system property by running the maven goal

`mvn help:evaluate`

And then entering

`${os.arch}`

Alternatively, the goal `help:system` lists all system properties (in no particular order.)

Comment: Beware, this method assumes you use a 64bits JVM on a 64bits system which isn't always true.

Most of the time people uses 32bits JVM on their system 32bits or not.

Comment: That's not true. A 32-bit vm will return x86 for the architecture even on x64. (If it didn't then it would fail, since trying to load a 64-bit dll under a 32-bit vm will fail.) I run a 64-bit OS, but often use a 32-bit vm. See my edit for an easy way to inspect this system property using maven.

Comment: <arch>amd64</arch> for 64 bits platform

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with profiles.This will only work in Sun's JVM.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>32bits</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>sun.arch.data.model</name>
                <value>32</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            ...
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>64bit</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>sun.arch.data.model</name>
                <value>64</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            ...
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Maven Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) may be helpful to you.