# how to access main/resources of a maven dependency lib?

Tags: java, maven

got a maven submodule project including set of dlls in main\resoursces. How can I access from my other module project ?

The maven profile detects guest os and download dlls submodule project similar to [Resolving a Maven dependency differently if the JVM in use is x86 or x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500664/resolving-a-maven-dependency-differently-if-the-jvm-in-use-is-x86-or-x64)

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a resource in your pom.xml file

```
<project>
    <build>
      <resources>
         <resource>
             <directory>${Submodule_path}</directory>
             <includes>
                <include>*.dll</include>
             </includes>
             <targetPath/>
         </resource>
      </resources>
    </build>    
 </project>
```

Other option is to use "[build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html)" and introduce there the source that you want.